# invert the loop in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm not sure if my title is exactly what I'm trying to do but in essence I'm getting the average of a list of lists and I want it to add not within the lists but across them:

```
listoflists = [[1,2,3], [1,0,4], [0,5,1]]
#want [1, 3.5, 2.67]
final = []
for i in range(len(listoflists)):
    count = 0
    val = 0
    for j in range(len(listoflists[i])):
        if listoflists[i][j] != 0:
            count += 1
            val += listoflists[i][j]
    final.append(float(val)/count)
print final #currently returns [2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
```

instead of adding 1, 2, 3, and getting the average 6/3=2, I want it to add 1, 1, 0 (first value in each list) and get 2/2=1 (if 0, don't count it)
How do I get the loop to do that instead?

Comment: Use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the list of lists then use [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to get the sum of the transposed lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list first, using zip

```
zip(*listoflists)
>>> [(1, 1, 0), (2, 0, 5), (3, 4, 1)]
```

Here's one way to do it:

```
final = []
for l in zip(*listoflists):
    final.append(float(sum(l)) / len([x for x in l if x != 0]))
print final
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use NumPy.

```
arr = np.array(listoflists)
sums = arr.sum(axis=0)
final = []    
for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
    final.append(sums[i]/np.count_nonzero(arr[:,i])
```

Or better yet to avoid the loop altogether.

```
arr = np.array(listoflists)
sums = arr.sum(0)
non_zeros = (arr != 0).sum(0)
final = sums / zon_zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
listoflists = [[1,2,3], [1,0,4], [0,5,1]]
second_list = zip(*listoflists)
new_list = map(list, second_list)

final_list = []
without_zero = []
for i in new_list:
    for b in i:
       if b != 0:
          without_zero.append(b)
    final_list.append(without_zero)
    without_zero = []

average = [sum(i)/float(len(i)) for i in final_list]

print average
```

Edit:
   another way just using list comprehension and zip:

```
listoflists = [[1,2,3], [1,0,4], [0,5,1]]
new_list = zip(*listoflists)
result = [sum([i for i in b if i != 0])/float(len([i for i in b if i != 0])) for b in new_list]
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from __future__ import division
map(lambda *column: sum(column)/sum(x>0 for x in column), *listoflists)
```

Another possibility (Python 3 only):

```
from statistics import mean
[mean(filter(None, column)) for column in zip(*listoflists)]
```

Alternative numpy implementation (works for Python 2 as well):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(listoflists)
np.average(a, axis=0, weights=a>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets reform your code to be a bit more Python like. In Python we can iterate (go through the list) and get the objects back directly, we don't really need to play with the index.

```
final = []
for i in listoflists:
    count = 0
    val = 0

    for j in i:
        if j != 0:
            count += 1
            val += j 
    final.append(float(val)/count)

print final
```

This code is the exact same as yours without the indexing, `j` is the actual sub items (the numbers) that we are getting.

---

To do what you want, Python has a handy [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) function which transposes sub lists. For example if we have the following lists `[1,2] , [3,4]` when we `zip([1,2],[3,4])` these lists, we get `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`

We can use this to do what you want by unpacking the list using the `*` symbol before the list of lists, and `zip()` supports this. Going back to our previous example we can make a list of list `x = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and pass x in with the `*` into zip to get what we want. `zip(*x)` we will get `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`. Combining these together with what you have will give you your desired results.

```
final = []
for i in zip(*listoflists):
    count = 0
    val = 0

    for j in i:
        if j != 0:
            count += 1
            val += j 
    final.append(float(val)/count)
```

---

We can improve this even more by using some more built in from such as [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) which will sum up all the items in the list if possible, and you already know `len()` which can be used with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out the `0`. From the docs:

> (item for item in iterable if item) if function is None.

So we are checking if the list contains item's that are of value, and `0` is fails when `if 0:`

```
final = []
for i in zip(*listoflists):
    if i: 
        final.append(float(sum(i))/len(filter(None, i)))
print final
```

---

We can go one step further and compression the function, by using one of the neatest thing Python has to offer, [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print [float(sum(i))/len(filter(None,i)) for i in zip(*listoflists)]
```

Note some of these answers may not be as optimal as others, but my answer is focused on different ways you can do it with only built-ins.